# How do I swap content

Tags: javascript, html, lifecycle, vue.js

how can I swap content of a div with Vue.js? I think I lack general lifecycle knowledge. Here is what I´ve got so far. After all I need to swap between two Vue-instances and ´d like to use only one lightbox container for them.

Here is what I´ve got so far: http://jsbin.com/qokerah/edit?html,js,output

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>  
</head>
<body>

  <script type="x-template" id="foo-template">
    <div class="text">{{ fooText }}</div>
    <div class="confirm" v-if="fooConfirm">confirmed</div>
  </script>

  <script type="x-template" id="bar-template">
    <div class="heading">{{ barHeading }}</div>
    <div class="info">{{ barInfo }}</div>
  </script>

  <div class="foo">
    <div class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="swapLightboxContent">Open foo template</div>
  </div>

  <div class="bar">
    <div class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="swapLightboxContent">Open bar template</div>
  </div>

  <div class="lightbox">
    <div class="lightbox-content">Show foo- or bar-template</div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var foo = new Vue({
  el: '.foo',
  data: {
    fooText: 'text',
    fooConfirm: false
  },
  methods: {
    swapLightboxContent: function () {
      console.log('Show foo-template');
    }
  }
});

var bar = new Vue({
  el: '.bar',
  data: {
    barHeading: 'text',
    barInfo: 'text'
  },
  methods: {
    swapLightboxContent: function () {
      console.log('Show bar-template');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my main misconception where:

I Used var foo and bar as new Vue() instances without having a parent "intersection" instance

so this is now working:

http://jsbin.com/tiwoco/edit?html,js,output

Still need to figure out if accessing the currentView item through vmFoo and vmBar instances shouldn´t be done in foo and bar components :)

Comment: You can pass any property to your child instance using `<component :is="currentView" :foo="bar" :a="b" :current-view="currentView"></component>`